# ActiveMQ: one message, multiple consumers

Tags: activemq-classic

Need your help, say I have a micro-services-like pipeline in which the micro-services communicate with each other through messaging (using ActiveMQ).

Say service1 queues a message to a certain queue, what if i want service2 and service3 both to consume that message (in a reliable manner, so topic won't work i guess).

Is there a way to do so?

Thanx,
Gili

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like ActiveMQ's [Virtual Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) feature to allow you to publish messages to a Topic and have those enqueued onto subscription queues for various Queue consumers to receive the same message and possibly load balance the work done to process them.

Comment: In our case we are facing issue as : one message is consumed by two consumers from same queue. We want to restrict one message only can be consumed by one  consumer.